# Drag and drop columns between QHeaderView and QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, qlistwidget, qheaderview

I am having troubled using the `QHeaderView` drag & drop feature. When I subclass a `QHeaderView`, I am able to accept drops with no issue. However, when I click on the `QHeaderView` and try to drag from one of the columns, nothing appears to happen.

Below I have re-implemented several drag events to simply print if they were called. However, only the `dragEnterEvent` is successful. No other event such as `startDrag` is ever called. My ultimate goal is to have a `QTableView` where I can drag columns from and to a `QListWidget` (essentially hiding the column) and the user can then drag the `QListWidget` item back onto the `QTableView` if they want the column and its data to be visible again. However, I can’t move forward until I can understand why the `QHeaderView` is not allowing me to drag. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class MyHeader(QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(Qt.Horizontal, parent)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def startDrag(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('start drag success')

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print('drag enter success')

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        print('drag leave success')

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        print('drag move success')

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        listWidget = QListWidget()
        listWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
        listWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)
        listWidget.addItem('item #1')
        listWidget.addItem('item #2')

        tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        header = MyHeader()
        tableWidget.setHorizontalHeader(header)
        tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Column 1", "Column 2"])

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter.addWidget(listWidget)
        splitter.addWidget(tableWidget)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form= Form()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QHeaderView` class does not use the drag and drop methods inherited from `QAbstractItemView`, because it never needs to initiate a drag operation. Drag and drop is only used for rearranging columns, and it is not necessary to use the `QDrag` mechanism for that.

Given this, it will be necessary to implement custom drag and drop handling (using `mousePressEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent` and `dropEvent`), and also provide functions for encoding and decoding the mime-data format that Qt uses to pass items between views. An event-filter will be needed for the table-widget, so that dropping is still possible when all columns are hidden; and also for the list-widget, to stop it copying items to itself.

The demo script below implements all of that. There are probably some more refinements needed, but it should be enough to get you started:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyHeader(QHeaderView):
    MimeType = 'application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'
    columnsChanged = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(Qt.Horizontal, parent)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self._dragstartpos = None

    def encodeMimeData(self, items):
        data = QByteArray()
        stream = QDataStream(data, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        for column, label in items:
            stream.writeInt32(0)
            stream.writeInt32(column)
            stream.writeInt32(2)
            stream.writeInt32(int(Qt.DisplayRole))
            stream.writeQVariant(label)
            stream.writeInt32(int(Qt.UserRole))
            stream.writeQVariant(column)
        mimedata = QMimeData()
        mimedata.setData(MyHeader.MimeType, data)
        return mimedata

    def decodeMimeData(self, mimedata):
        data = []
        stream = QDataStream(mimedata.data(MyHeader.MimeType))
        while not stream.atEnd():
            row = stream.readInt32()
            column = stream.readInt32()
            item = {}
            for count in range(stream.readInt32()):
                key = stream.readInt32()
                item[key] = stream.readQVariant()
            data.append([item[Qt.UserRole], item[Qt.DisplayRole]])
        return data

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._dragstartpos = event.pos()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton and
            self._dragstartpos is not None and
            (event.pos() - self._dragstartpos).manhattanLength() >=
            QApplication.startDragDistance()):
            column = self.logicalIndexAt(self._dragstartpos)
            data = [column, self.model().headerData(column, Qt.Horizontal)]
            self._dragstartpos = None
            drag = QDrag(self)
            drag.setMimeData(self.encodeMimeData([data]))
            action = drag.exec(Qt.MoveAction)
            if action != Qt.IgnoreAction:
                self.setColumnHidden(column, True)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        mimedata = event.mimeData()
        if mimedata.hasFormat(MyHeader.MimeType):
            if event.source() is not self:
                for column, label in self.decodeMimeData(mimedata):
                    self.setColumnHidden(column, False)
                event.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.ignore()
        else:
            super().dropEvent(event)

    def setColumnHidden(self, column, hide=True):
        count = self.count()
        if 0 <= column < count and hide != self.isSectionHidden(column):
            if hide:
                self.hideSection(column)
            else:
                self.showSection(column)
            self.columnsChanged.emit(count - self.hiddenSectionCount())

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.listWidget = QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.listWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.listWidget.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        header = MyHeader(self)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeader(header)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)

        labels = ["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4"]
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)
        for column, label in enumerate(labels):
            if column > 1:
                item = QListWidgetItem(label)
                item.setData(Qt.UserRole, column)
                self.listWidget.addItem(item)
                header.hideSection(column)

        header.columnsChanged.connect(
            lambda count: self.tableWidget.setAcceptDrops(not count))
        self.tableWidget.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        splitter.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Drop:
            if source is self.tableWidget.viewport():
                self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().dropEvent(event)
                return True
            else:
                event.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__=='__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.setGeometry(600, 50, 600, 200)
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and example. This has put me far ahead than what I was expecting. 
One question: the only issue I see is if the user were to drag a column from the QHeaderView back onto the QHeaderView (instead of the QListWidget) which essentially hides the dragged column from view with no way to restore the dragged column. I was trying to find a means to ignore the drag in this situation. 
I'm sure the answer is simple but after several hours of going over the source code I was unable to find an efficient solution.

Comment: @ArtVandelay. I have fixed the problem (in the `dropEvent` method). A further refinement would be to set the drag cursor whilst the header is dragging over itself - but I'm going to leave that to you ;-)

Comment: Awesome! I have wanted to add this functionality to my app for quite some time now and you've helped make that happen. Furthermore, the source code you provided has given me a better understanding of some of Qt's lower level features. Again, your time and effort is much appreciated.

Comment: @ArtVandelay. You're welcome - thanks for the feedback.